# Checking every third column based on criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having an issue with coming up with a way in which I could copy data from Destination Sheet: Date Issue, validation date and revision. To a second sheet which has the employees names.

Here is the layout of sheet with the employees (Destination Sheet):
[image: Destination Sheet]

Here is the sheet I would like to pull data from:
[image: Data Sheet]

I tried using formulas like:

`=IF($A2<>"", INDEX(Sheet2!C:C, MATCH($A2, Sheet2!A:A, 0)), "")`

But I cant get it to work and this needs to be repeated for every column for every ID Code. Would VBA be the only way forward?

Expecting: Correct data for the correct person and correct ID Code to be transferred to the correct cells in the destination sheet.

Comment: 1. Unmerge and fill the merged cells on Datasheet with the values
2. Concatenate ID code with headers on destination sheet  and data sheet like [ID Code]&"Date Issue" in the specified string
3. Then use INDEX/MATCH formula

If you have uploaded at least excel file with headers, I'd have written an exact formula

Comment: VBA is an option. In source worksheet, `SOP_xx` has multiple date, how does it fit into a cell on destination sheet?